# Managing default shaders in OpenGL/GLFW

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, glfw

I'm writing an OpenGL wrapper library using glfw and I want to ship shaders with my code. These shaders need to be compiled after the glfw context gets created. I want to have these shaders as static variables of a class.

I currently have a "DefaultShaders" class that stores static pointers which get assigned when the init_shaders() function is called;

DefaultShaders.h

```
class DefaultShaders {
   private:
        static const std::string basic_vertex_source;
        static const std::string basic_fragment_source;

        static const std::string skybox_vertex_source;
        static const std::string skybox_fragment_source;


        static const std::string framebuffer_vertex_source;
        static const std::string framebuffer_fragment_source;

        static const ShaderProgram *default_program;
        static const ShaderProgram *skybox_program;
        static const ShaderProgram *framebuffer_program;

    public:

        static void init_shaders();

        static void delete_shaders();

        static const ShaderProgram &get_default_program();

        static const ShaderProgram &get_skybox_program();


        static const ShaderProgram&get_framebuffer_program();

    };
```

DefaultShaders.cpp

```
const std::string DefaultShaders::basic_vertex_source = "#version 330 core\n"
                                                            "layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;\n"
                                                            "layout (location = 1) in vec2 tex_coord;\n"
                                                            "layout (location = 2) in vec3 aNormal;\n"
                                                            "\n"
                                                            "uniform mat4 model;\n"
                                                            "uniform mat4 view;\n"
                                                            "uniform mat4 projection;\n"
                                                            "out vec2 TexCoord;\n"
                                                            "out vec3 Normal;\n"
                                                            "\n"
                                                            "void main()\n"
                                                            "{\n"
                                                            "    TexCoord=tex_coord;\n"
                                                            "    Normal=mat3(transpose(inverse(model))) * aNormal;\n"
                                                            "    mat4 mvp=projection*view*model;\n"
                                                            "    gl_Position = mvp*vec4(aPos, 1.0);\n"
                                                            "}";


    const std::string DefaultShaders::basic_fragment_source = "#version 330 core\n"
                                                              "out vec4 FragColor;\n"
                                                              "\n"
                                                              "in vec2 TexCoord;\n"
                                                              "\n"
                                                              "uniform sampler2D ourTexture;\n"
                                                              "in vec3 Normal;\n"
                                                              "\n"
                                                              "void main()\n"
                                                              "{\n"
                                                              "    vec3 norm = normalize(Normal);\n"
                                                              "    vec3 lightDir=vec3(0,1,0);\n"
                                                              "    float diff = max(dot(norm, lightDir), 0.4);\n"
                                                              "\n"
                                                              "\n"
                                                              "    FragColor = texture(ourTexture, TexCoord)*diff;\n"
                                                              "}";


    const std::string DefaultShaders::skybox_vertex_source = "#version 330 core\n"
                                                             "layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;\n"
                                                             "\n"
                                                             "out vec3 TexCoords;\n"
                                                             "\n"
                                                             "uniform mat4 pv;\n"
                                                             "\n"
                                                             "void main()\n"
                                                             "{\n"
                                                             "    TexCoords = aPos;\n"
                                                             "    vec4 pos=pv * vec4(aPos, 1.0);"
                                                             "    gl_Position =pos.xyww;\n"
                                                             "}";


    const std::string DefaultShaders::skybox_fragment_source = "#version 330 core\n"
                                                               "out vec4 FragColor;\n"
                                                               "\n"
                                                               "in vec3 TexCoords;\n"
                                                               "\n"
                                                               "uniform samplerCube skybox;\n"
                                                               "\n"
                                                               "void main()\n"
                                                               "{    \n"
                                                               "    FragColor = texture(skybox, TexCoords);\n"
                                                               "}";


    const std::string DefaultShaders::framebuffer_vertex_source = "#version 330 core\n"
                                                                  "layout (location = 0) in vec2 aPos;\n"
                                                                  "layout (location = 1) in vec2 aTexCoords;\n"
                                                                  "\n"
                                                                  "out vec2 TexCoords;\n"
                                                                  "\n"
                                                                  "void main()\n"
                                                                  "{\n"
                                                                  "    gl_Position = vec4(aPos.x, aPos.y, 0.0, 1.0); \n"
                                                                  "    TexCoords = aTexCoords;\n"
                                                                  "} ";


    const std::string DefaultShaders::framebuffer_fragment_source = "#version 330 core\n"
                                                                    "out vec4 FragColor;\n"
                                                                    "  \n"
                                                                    "in vec2 TexCoords;\n"
                                                                    "\n"
                                                                    "uniform sampler2D screenTexture;\n"
                                                                    "\n"
                                                                    "void main()\n"
                                                                    "{ \n"
                                                                    "    FragColor = texture(screenTexture, TexCoords);\n"
                                                                    "}";


    const ShaderProgram *DefaultShaders::default_program;
    const ShaderProgram *DefaultShaders::skybox_program;
    const ShaderProgram *DefaultShaders::framebuffer_program;

    const ShaderProgram &DefaultShaders::get_default_program() {
        return *default_program;

    }

    const ShaderProgram &DefaultShaders::get_skybox_program() {
        return *skybox_program;
    }


    const ShaderProgram &DefaultShaders::get_framebuffer_program() {
        return *framebuffer_program;
    }

    void DefaultShaders::init_shaders() {
        VertexShader basic_vertex_shader(basic_vertex_source);
        FragmentShader basic_fragment_shader(basic_fragment_source);

        VertexShader skybox_vertex_shader(skybox_vertex_source);
        FragmentShader skybox_fragment_shader(skybox_fragment_source);


        VertexShader framebuffer_vertex_shader(framebuffer_vertex_source);
        FragmentShader framebuffer_fragment_shader(framebuffer_fragment_source);


        default_program = new ShaderProgram(basic_vertex_shader, basic_fragment_shader);
        skybox_program = new ShaderProgram(skybox_vertex_shader, skybox_fragment_shader);
        framebuffer_program = new ShaderProgram(framebuffer_vertex_shader, framebuffer_fragment_shader);
    }

    void DefaultShaders::delete_shaders() {
        delete default_program;
        delete skybox_program;
        delete framebuffer_program;
    }
```

Is there a better way of shipping shaders with my code?

Comment: Maybe you want [raw strings](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal)?

Comment: I have also seen somewhere people using preprocessor wrapper that stringifies the whole GLSL code,which in such a case looks like regular C code in the editor. IMHO ,it is even better than using R literals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As HolyBlackCat said, raw strings are a better way of storing strings inside your program. If you are targeting Windows only, you can use resource files to store your shaders. [This guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/working-with-resource-files?view=vs-2019) should help. If you want to also compile for Mac and Linux, you can keep storing the shaders as you're doing right now (or use raw strings just for some more readability) or use SPIR-V shaders. Sadly, these last ones are not available in most computers because they require a recent OpenGL version. They are also harder to code because they are lower level.

Comment: On Linux/Mac you can use [this](https://balau82.wordpress.com/2012/02/19/linking-a-binary-blob-with-gcc/) as a replacement for Windows resources.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, it's a good idea. As a linux programmer I didn't even know they existed.